# Can the range of an aegis's astral suit's ranged attack be increased?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, psionics

How can the range of the [aegis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/)'s [astral suit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits)'s 1-point customization ranged attack be increased beyond 30 feet?

Comment: The feat [Far Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/far-shot-combat-final/) no longer increases a weapon's range increment like it did in *3.5e* but, instead, decreases the penalties for long-range attacks. Also, during my edit, I wasn't entirely clear if you meant *range* (as in *maximum range* — which for the customization ranged attack is 300 ft.) or *range increment* (30 ft.), so I leave it to you to edit in that distinction.

Comment: You're a big help, thanks...I knew that max range of the attack is 300 ft, but comes at a penalty to the attack roll. I was wondering if increasing the the range increment would eliminate such penalties. IT's given me good insight to what to do to modify what I want done.  Besides a reduction to the penalty is better than full thing.

Answer (score 2):

**The standard Range Increment of your attack will always be 30 feet.**

That being said, what you can look at to reach further targets is how to improve your own attack rolls, or decrease the target AC.

To increase your own attack rolls, you can look into the following options:

- Increase your Dex modifier: All ranged attacks use your Dex bonus to add to your chance to hit.
- Use the [Far Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/far-shot-combat-final/) feat: This will decrease the range penalty, so that you can reach further distances with less penalties.

To decrease your opponents AC, you can:

- Invest in the 2-point customization option [Energy Blast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits): This will convert your attack to a Ranged Touch Attack, which will target Touch AC
- Find any other method to remove your opponents DEX bonus, such as being flat-footed